# Sunspot Solr index time boost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I try to use document boost on index time, but it seems, that it hasn't any effect. I've set up my model for Sunspot like

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do
    text :name, :boost => 2.0, stored: true
    text :description, :boost => 1.2, stored: false
    boost { boost_value }
  end
end
```

The `boost_value` field is a field in the database, where a user can change the boost in the frontend. It gets stored at index time (either the first time I build the index, or when a product is updated). I have about 3600 products in my database, with a default `boost_value`of `1.0`. Two of the products got different `boost_values`, one with `5.0` and the other with `2.0`.

However, If I just want to retrieve all products from Solr, the document boost seems to have no effect on the order or the score:

```
solr = ::Sunspot.new_search(Spree::Product) do |query|
  query.order_by("score", "desc")
  query.paginate(page: 1, per_page: Spree::Product.count)
end

solr.execute
solr.results.first
```

The Solr query itself looks like this:

`http://localhost:8982/solr/collection1/select?sort=score+desc&start=0&q=*:*&wt=xml&fq=type:Spree\:\:Product&rows=3600&debugQuery=true`

I've appended a `debugQuery=true` at the end, to see what the scores are. But there are no scores shown.

The same things happens, when I search for a term. For examle, I have 2 products that have a unique string `testtest` inside the `name` field. When I search for this term, the document boost has no effect on the order.

So my questions are:

- Can per document index time boosting be used based on a database field?
- Does the document boost has any effect for `q=*:*`?
- How can I debug this?
- Or do I have to specify, that solr should involve the document boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solr, the boosts only apply to text searches, so it applies only if you do a fulltext search.
Something like this:

```
solr = ::Sunspot.new_search(Spree::Product) do |query|
  fulltext 'somesearch'
  query.order_by("score", "desc") # I think this isn't necesary
  query.paginate(page: 1, per_page: Spree::Product.count)
end
```

If you want to boost certain products more than others:

```
solr = ::Sunspot.new_search(Spree::Product) do |query|
  fulltext 'somesearch' do
    boost(2.0) { with(:featured, true) }
  end
  query.paginate(page: 1, per_page: Spree::Product.count)
end
```

As you see, this is much powerfull than boosting at index time, and you could put different boostings for different conditions, all at query time with no need of reindexing if you want to change the boost or the conditions.

Comment: Ok, I get this. But also for fulltext searches, the document boost doesn't have any effect. Do you know how I can debug this? Or how I can list the document boost or how the calculation is done?

Comment: mmm, no idea on how to debug that. Although I find it better to boost at query time than at indexing time, because you can change the boosting anytime you want without having to reindex everything...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if I understand that whole thing right, but I think you can't set the document boost at query time. Am I right? The problem behind this is, that it should be possible to feature some products. This means, that when retrieving the products through a search, or just when filtering for categories, the featured products should be on top.

Comment: I'm not sure right now if you can boost a document at query time, but it's fairly simple to do what you need. Say you have a field that's called 'featured', then you could boost those documents only. See updated answer...

Comment: Hmmm, but what about the field `boost_value` mentioned in my question? How can I invoke this value, e.g. Doc1 has a boost value with `2.0` and Doc2 with `3.0`. Let's say we search for a term `somesearch` and Doc1 gets a score of 10, and Doc2 would get a score of 8. Is it possible to invoke the `boost_value` so that Doc2 gets a higher score?

Comment: But that boost_value must come from somewhere... isn't that data stored someplace in the model?

Comment: Yes, that value is stored in the model, and it gets indexed in solr as the document boost. And every product can have it's own boost value, so that it can be regulated, which products are more important.

Comment: Oh, I get what you are trying to do... 
You need to keep in mind that it boosts the match for the text search, it doesn't assure that the elements with higher boost come first.
Eg: 
Doc1: has text 'hello world world', with boost 2
Doc2: has text 'hello hello world', with boost 3
If yoy search 'hello' Doc2 will come first, if you search world Doc1 will come first since it's a better match. (not tested)
If you allways want the docs with higher boost_value to appear before irregarding the text boosting you should use order:
query.order_by(:boost_value, :score)